# See full effect of a cascading delete in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a MySQL database that is decently large and has various primary and foreign keys interconnecting everything. I'm trying to build up a spreadsheet of the effects of dropping various columns from various tables. I've imported the basic .sql file into MySQL Workbench (can't seem to get one with populated tables imported and can't connect directly to the database with Workbench due to infrastructure setup, but I don't think I really need them populated) and have been using visual diagram to help.

But what I would love to do is set everything to cascade on delete (which I know how to do) then get some kind of result on what would happen if I delete a column from table X. Is there anyway to do this? (Obviously nullable foreign keys would do different things when they are or aren't populated, but I would be fine with assuming everything isn't null and seeing the results).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try yo clone your DB and test it. Or you can try to force to uncommitt the deletions see the effect and after do a rollback.